# Error Model name is not defined in Wagtail CMS

Tags: wagtail

When I run a QuerySet on a class model in Wagtail I get the error.

```
NameError: name 'BlogPage' is not defined
```

Here is the code:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import index


class IndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)


    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname='full'),
    ]


class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + (
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full")
    ]
```

However, if I run a QuerySet using the Parent Page class I get the expected result.

```
Page.objects.all()
[<Page: Root>, <Page: Homepage>, <Page: Blog Page Index>, <Page: Post number 1>, <Page: Post number 2>, <Page: Post number 3>]
```

What will be to correct way of defining the BlogPage and other page classes that inherit from the Page class?

Comment: What line of code are you running when you get the `NameError: name 'BlogPage' is not defined` error?

Comment: @gasman, The line of code I'm running when I get the error message is: BlogPage.objects.all()

Comment: I'm guessing you've done an `import wagtail` if you're using the command line (are you?); have you also done a `from myapp.models import BlogPage`?

Comment: @FlipperPA, I was not importing myapp.models import BlogPage, thanks this fixed it.

Comment: I've added it as a proper answer of you could mark it correct. Take care!

Answer (score 2):

At the command line, after you:

```
import wagtail
```

...you also need to import your BlogPage model like so:

```
from myapp.models import BlogPage
```

Good luck!